# Why does it take me so long to launch an ASP.NET web site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, browser

I am running VS 2008 SP1 on a pretty high-powered Win XP machine.  My startup project is a web project that was written by another developer (I'm not that well versed in web development).  Start Options = launch specific page, Server = default Web server, debuggers = ASP.NET.

When I push F5, my browser opens a new tab in Firefox (my default browser) - but then it takes over 3 minutes for the web page to appear!  I tried "step into" instead of F5, and the first executable line of code is only hit after that same 3 minutes.

Other developers do not have this problem.  There is clearly something wrong with my configuration, but I haven't the faintest idea where to start looking.

Your suggestions are most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were issues reported with FireFox and the VS built-in development server. It has something to do with IPv6 issue.

With me it's similar: IE/Opera do it quickly, FireFox/Safari terribly slow.

You should be able to fix it the following way:

In your FF type in the "about:config" address. Then find the setting "network.dns.disableIPv6" and set it to true. Now it should become fast.